# dependencies between compiled modules in python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

Let's say I have two modules in a python project that are written in C++ and exposed with boost::python.

mod1.hpp

```
#ifndef MOD1_HPP
#define MOD1_HPP

#include <boost/python.hpp>

int square(int x);

#endif
```

mod1.cpp

```
#include "mod1.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

int square(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE (mod1)
{
    def("square",&square);
}
```

mod2.hpp

```
#ifndef MOD2_HPP
#define MOD2_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "mod1.hpp"

int myfunc(int x);

#endif
```

mod2.cpp

```
#include "mod2.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

int myfunc(int x)
{
    int y = square(x);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE (mod2)
{
    def("myfunc",&myfunc);
}
```

As you can see, mod2 is using a function defined in mod1. Compiled without the boost::python wrapper and with a main function, it works perfectly fine.

Now the compile script

setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from setuptools import setup, Extension

mod1 = Extension('mod1',
                 sources = ['mod1.cpp'],
                 libraries = ['boost_python'])

mod2 = Extension('mod2',
                 sources = ['mod2.cpp'],
                 libraries = ['boost_python'])

setup(name='foo',
      version='0.0',
      description='',
      ext_modules=[mod1,mod2],
      install_requires=['distribute'])
```

it compiles fine. Then I move to `build/lib.linux-i686-2.7` and launch python2

```
>>> import mod1
>>> import mod2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./mod2.so: undefined symbol: _Z6squarei
>>>
```

Obviously there's a problem with mod2 not finding mod1. How can I fix that ? How can I define several C modules in a python project and allow them to use each others ?

Answer (score 1):

Since mod1 is a Python extension, the clean approach would be to use it just like any other Python module:

```
object mod1 = import("mod1");
object square = mod1.attr("square");
int y = extract<int>(square(x));
```

Comment: Interesting. But it would mean that any call between modules add a double layer of conversion, C->python->C ... Is it really the only way ?

Comment: Well, I suppose you can expose a direct C++ interface to your functions, and link to mod1 like to some other dynamic C++ library.

Comment: Is it not precisely what I'm doing in my example ? or maybe my setup.py file is missing some parameters passed at linking ?

Comment: mod2 would need to be linked to mod1. I'm not sure if you can do that using setup.py to build. I'd prefer to put shared functionality in a separate pure C++ library (built using C++ tools) and link to that from mod1 and mod2.

Comment: You could also simply add mod1.cpp to the sources list of mod2

Comment: Adding mod2.cpp partly fixes the problem (I have to import mod1 before mod2 in order for it to work).But if I do that I'm not taking advantage of the shared library mod1.so -- I'm rather embedding mod1 code into mod2.so -- which is not really an option for an actual project