# linking between two modules with distutils

Tags: python, boost-python, bjam

I have recently [exposed a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443652/dependencies-between-compiled-modules-in-python) when working with several compiled C++ modules and would like to rephrase the question.

I have two modules 'mod1' and 'mod2'. They are compiled as two distinct 'ext_modules' in my setup.py, as shown here :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from setuptools import setup, Extension

mod1 = Extension('mod1',
                 sources = ['mod1.cpp'],
                 libraries = ['boost_python'])

mod2 = Extension('mod2',
                 sources = ['mod2.cpp'],
                 libraries = ['boost_python'])

setup(name='foo',
      version='0.0',
      description='',
      ext_modules=[mod1,mod2],
      install_requires=['distribute'])
```

But internally, 'mod2.hpp' is including 'mod1.hpp', as the first module is defining stuff that is used by the second module.

EDIT : this will compile fine, but then :

```
$> cd build/lib.linux-i686-2.7
$> python2 -c "import mod1 ; import mod2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./mod2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6ParentD2Ev
```

Here, "Parent" is the name of a class defined in mod1 and used in mod2.

EDIT2 : another weird behaviour I don't understand :

```
$> cd build/lib.linux-i686-2.7
$> python2
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov 21 2011, 17:24:32) 
[GCC 4.6.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mod2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./mod2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6ParentD2Ev
>>> import mod1
>>> import mod2
Segmentation fault
```

Here, importing mod2 first fails. But if I try agin after importing mod1, I get a segfault.

---

Both modules are built as shared libraries - but if I'm not mistaken, mod2 needs to be linked to mod1 in order to work, as it needs stuff defined in mod1. Is it possible to define such a dependency with setuptools/distribute ?

Something like :

```
mod2 = Extension('mod2',
                 sources = ['mod2.cpp'],
                 libraries = ['boost_python',mod1])
```

From my various readings, it looks like it is possible to do something like this with boost's bjam utility - unfortunately, I didn't manage to use it (even to compile the example) on my system.

Things I have tried:

- adding 'mod1.cpp' to the sources of mod2. It works (kind of: I must import mod1 before mod2 to make it work) but I'm loosing the interest of having modules as shared objects.

Workarouds:

- importing mod1 as a regular python module in mod2, but that would put an extra layer of python within my C++ code

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I could not find how to do that with distutils / distribute. So I switched to cmake, and so far it works flawlessly !

with cmake, you can easily compile one module as a shared library, and later add this shared library to the dependencies of another module.

Comment: I believe this is the right way to go. The problem is that the command to build the shared library is not portable in general, although I guess cmake takes care of that for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your mod2 depend of mod1, then, import explicitely mod1 before mod2:

- when mod1 will be imported (loaded with `dlopen()`), all symbols of mod1 will be loaded in memory
- when mod2 will be imported, `dlopen()` will resolve and use symbol already loaded in memory

That's just an alternative :)

Comment: not sure of what you mean by "import explicitely". If I compile, go to 'build/lib.linux-i686-2.7', run python2 and do 'import mod1 ; import mod2', I get 'ImportError: ./mod2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6ParentD2Ev'